# jQuery - add css to make text smaller

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building up a table using jQuery and then appending the information together into the tbody after looping through the results of a returned JSON set of data. It all works great, however with one line of the code I'm adding a class to the 'td' and then adding the text. In the text I want to make part of it smaller, my code as follows:

```
var table = $('#my-table');
var row = $('<tr>');
var scorer = $('<td>').addClass("pp_team").css("background-image", "url(/img/" + encodeURIComponent(this.team) + ".png)").text(this.player + ' (' + this.teamshort + ')');
var goals = $('<td>').text(this.goals).css("font-weight","Bold");
row.append(scorer,goals);
table.append(row);
```

I'm trying to have this part as smaller text than the rest in the scorer line:

```
' (' + this.teamshort + ')
```

but cant seem to find a suitable place to add css inline to it.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you could add a span tag to resize the text in question:

```
<span style="font-size:0.8em"> (my team name) </span>
```

For more information on font-size see (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).

**Note** - By the way, a better way to do this is to use a class to style your text. For that you would end up putting the following class in a css file:

```
.smaller-font {
   font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

And your code would look something like:

```
' <span class="smaller-font">(' + this.teamshort + ')</span>'
```

That is - if I am reading your code correctly! Hope that helps!

**Edit** - As others have noted you will want to make sure you use the ".html" jQuery call instead of the ".text" call when appending this to your table.

Comment: Don't forget to use .html instead of .text

Comment: that was it! using html instead of text I can use bootstraps 'small' - perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML & CSS instead.

```
.html(this.player + '<span style="font-size: 7px;">(' + this.teamshort + ')</span>');
```